# What is the recomended mechanism of parallelizing Expression Trees?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, task-parallel-library

given a scenario where I am serializing & deserializing Expression Trees that operate on IEnumerable s for distributed processing scale-out, I would like to also automate scale-up: 
On execution of this Expression Tree , I would like to apply the TPL AsParallel() operator.

What is the best practice for doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your problem is. I am assuming you want

```
IEnumerable<string> enumerable = new List<string>();
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<bool>>> expression = a => a.Select(b => b == true);
```

To auto scale up and out. The thing is, AsParallel() just returns a class that implements a different GetEnumerator() method. It still operates over an IEnumerable<T> interface. So why don't you implement

```
Expression<Func<ParallelQuery<TSource>, IEnumerable<bool>>> expression = a => a.Select(b => b == true);
```

by default? Then have something like:

```
void Execute(Expression<Func<ParallelQuery<string>, IEnumerable<bool>>> expression, IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    ParallelQuery<string> parStrings;
    if (!typeof (ParallelQuery<string>).IsAssignableFrom(strings.GetType()))
        parStrings = strings as ParallelQuery<string>;
    else
        parStrings = strings.AsParallel();

    expression.Compile()(parStrings);
}
```

Long story short. Have your expression operate over ParallelQuery<T> by default, and convert your IEnumerable<T> to ParallelQuery<T>. Otherwise you looking at node traversal/query recomposition.
(Not sure if that answers your question. but blabbers on anyway.)

Just a note of warning Expression.Compile() is a very heavy method. If you want performance, avoid it if possible.